# In a binary tree print nodes which can not be searched by binary search

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search

I am trying to print all the binary tree nodes which can not be searched by binary search algorithm. Since BST is also based on binary search algorithm so I was trying to print nodes which do not comply BST structure.

The below code snippet fails for a case where right leaf value is greater than the root's root for example :

```
public class PrintBinarySearchable {
    static class Node {
        int key, height;
        Node left, right;

        public Node(int d) {
            key = d;
            left = right = null;
        }
    }

    Node prev;

    private void printSearchable(Node node, Node prev, boolean isRight) {
        if (node == null)
            return;
        if (prev == null)
            System.out.print(node.key + " ");

        printSearchable(node.left, node, false);

        if (!isRight && prev != null && node.key < prev.key)
            System.out.print(node.key + " ");

        if (isRight && prev != null && node.key > prev.key)
            System.out.print(node.key + " ");

        printSearchable(node.right, node, true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node root = new Node(7);
        root.left = new Node(2);
        root.right = new Node(9);
        root.left.left = new Node(1);
        root.left.right = new Node(51);

        PrintBinarySearchable tree = new PrintBinarySearchable();
        tree.printSearchable(root);
    }

    private void printSearchable(Node root) {
        printSearchable(root, null, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a homework assignment so I'm not going to give a complete answer here. Instead, I'll give you some tips on how to solve this.

- Rather than worry about whether a node is left/right and what its parent is to determine whether it's searchable, do the check from the parent. If you have a parent, you can determine whether its descendants are searchable.
- If you're making the determination from the parent, you don't need special cases in your recursion—just call `printSearchable(node.right);` and `printSearchable(node.left)` within `printSearchable`. Then you can just call `printSearchable(root)` and it will print all the nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the response Don and this is not a homework assignment. 

I am still unsure about how I can compare the value of current node with the it's root's root. 

For example, root 7 has two children node 2 in left and node 9 in right. Now node 2 has two children node 1 and node 51. Node 51 is a searchable node w.r.t. node 2 but it is invalid node w.r.t. node 2's parent i.e. node 7. 
How will your suggestion work out in this scenario ?